# Filtering out node by title

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a site running in Drupal 6 and I'm using Views to display content from several feeds I am importing.

There is a node being created in one of the feeds that I do not want to have shown (or even created at all, if I can help it) & there doesn't appear to be a way to negatively filter out nodes from being displayed by title. Is there a way to do this with any efficiency or might there be some other hack around this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

-B

Answer (score 1):

Views does allow you to filter out a node with a specific title. On the edit-view page, do the following:

- Click the [+] on the Filters box
- Check 'Node: Title' and click [Add]
- Select 'Is not equal to' as operator and enter the unwanted title as value
- Click [Update] and save your view

Comment: Thank you Marc! Much appreciated.

-B

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you feel that's appropriate :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just unpublish the nodes you don't want and add a filter for 'node:published = yes'. Unless the nodes you want to hide always have certain words in the title it will be hard to do it with a title filter.